# How can I invite existing GAds account to my MCK via API?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

Please help me how can I invite existing Google Ads account to my MCK via API?

I can't find any information about it in docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this using `ManagedCustomerService` and `mutateLink` [method](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/ManagedCustomerService#mutateLink). There are some examples and links in API documentation: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview